# How to make only one line list wider than screen?

Tags: css, list, user-interface

I have a list, which length is variable,it could have 4 items or 30 items.

The issue is that this list is being rendered as a marquee, through a Javascript that is working, but items reach the screen width and then they pass to next line.

I want to have all the items on the same line, so then I could move the list to recreate the marquee effect.

[image: What I have and What I want]

```
<div class="submenu-container">
<div id="agrupador">
 <ul style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;" class="submenu" id="moverlo">
       <li> Item </li>
       <li> Item </li>
       <li> Item </li>
       <li> Item </li>
       <li> Item </li>
       <li> Item </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>

    .submenu-container {
    background:#F0F7FF;
    border-bottom:1px silver solid;
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:4px;
    background:none;
    *display: inline; /* IE */
    float:left;
}

.submenu {
    margin:0;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    clear:none;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

And with javascript:

```
function ClonarAvisos(){
var width = alertSize(); // Usable window width
var xVarScreen = width - $('moverlo').getWidth();
alert($('moverlo').getWidth());
$('moverlo').setStyle({ width: $('moverlo').getWidth() + xVarScreen });
$('agrupador').setStyle({ width: $('moverlo').getWidth() * 2 });
var clon = Element.clone('moverlo', true);
clon.id = 'moverlo2';
$('agrupador').insert(clon);
```

}

```
function MoveNoticias(p) {
//Función que imita el comportamiento del Tag "marquee"
new Effect.Move('agrupador', {
    x: -3,
    y: 0,
    mode: 'relative',
    duration: 0.1,
    afterFinish: function() {
        var offSetDistance = $('agrupador').offsetLeft ;
        offSetDistance = Math.abs(offSetDistance);
        var gettingWidth = $('moverlo').getWidth() ; 
        if ( offSetDistance >= gettingWidth ) {
            Element.setStyle('agrupador', {left: '0px' });
        }
        MoveNoticias();
    }
});
}
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the `float: left` from the `li`, and adding `white-space: nowrap` to the 'ul'.

I tried that here: http://jsfiddle.net/76d6p/

Comment: i did the same but you were faster ;), my version on jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/zVSCV/](http://jsfiddle.net/zVSCV/)

Comment: It works, but I have the lists (because I must clone the original to make the marquee effect) to be float to left, so it keep on the same line. Doing your fix, there is a point where both overlaps, dont you know whay? Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you have a working example (maybe even another JSFiddle)?